# Removing button when Score is submitted

Tags: php

I want to have a certain part of code(focus on the start exam button first) removed after a score is submitted. Kinda in the same way it echoes completed when a score is bigger then -1. I only managed to get rid of the first 1 everytime in the loop but it only needs to remove completed ones. It is not my code and I am struggling to find the solution. How can I manage to remove the button for finished exams? Without removing the loop and hardadding the exams when they are bought.

```
div class="col-sm-4">
    
            
<?php 

 
    $product_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_product_id' ) ? $item->get_product_id() : 
$item['product_id'];
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ), 'single-post- 
thumbnail' );?>
     <div class="exam-image"> <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" height="300" width="350"></div>
    <?php $product_name = method_exists( $item, 'name' ) ? $item->name() : $item['name'];
     echo '<div class="product-name-exam">'.$product_name.'</h3>';
    $purchase_note= get_post_meta($product_id, '_purchase_note');
    ?>
      
**<div class="exam-start-button"><a href="<?php echo $purchase_note[0];?>" class="exam-start-now" 
  id="exam-start-button" >Start Exam Now</a></div>**           
  
    
   </div>
   <?php }
   
                  
          }

       ?>
       </div>
       </div>
       
        
    

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables" border='1' 
     style="margin-top:20px">
        <thead class="examhead">
            <tr>
            <th>#</th>
                <th>Exam Name</th>
                <th>Score/Max Score</th>
        <th>Date of Exam</th>
                <th>Status of Exam</th>
                    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
     <?php if(!empty($getuserdata)){ foreach($getuserdata as $key=>$value){ ?>
    <?php if(isset($value->id)){ ?> 
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td><?php echo $key+1?></td>
                    <td><?php echo getexamFormdata($value->form_id);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->score.' / '.$value->max_score;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s A',strtotime($value->date));?></td>
                     
                  
                       
                       <?php  $exam_name = getexamFormdata($value->form_id);
                     $score_total = $value->score; 
                     
                     
                    
                      
                     if ($score_total > -1) { ?>
                 
            
                   <td><?php echo 'Completed';?></td>
    


    

          
             
                       <?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give ID for the div you want to disappear. Then make Javascript function where you set display none for that div ID.

Like this:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button> 

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; 
    }
</script>
```

You are new user, so remember to accept answer if it is working.
You can accept it left using right icon.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that but then it will only remove the first entry and the button will be back when you go back to the page. It is an exam dashboard